# React Navigation: Dynamically hide Header

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

In my React Native app for Android, for a certain component I want to hide the header of the main StackNavigator.

I read so much about using `static navigationOptions` like this:

```
  static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
      header: null,
    };
  };
```

... but I just can't figure out how to use it properly.

Here is `App.ts`, where the main StackNavigator is located:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, View, StyleSheet, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

import Test from './src/screens/Test/Test';
import LandingPage from './src/screens/LandingPage/LandingPage';

class RootComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {    
    return (
      <View>            
        <LandingPage />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LandingPage: {
      screen: RootComponent,
      navigationOptions: {
        header: null,
      },
    },
    Test: { // The Header of this screen should be hidden as soon as a Button inside Test is pressed
      screen: Test,
      navigationOptions: {
        title: 'Test Title',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LandingPage',
  },
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}
```

This is the component `Test.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image,View} from 'react-native';

import TestBody from '../../components/organisms/TestBody/TestBody';

type Props = {};

const Test: React.FC<Props> = ({}) => {
  const navigationOptions = { // should I do the configuration here?
    header: null,
  };

function hideHeader() {
 // How to set the Header null here?
}

  return (
    <View>
      <TestBody />
      <Button
       title={'Press me and the header will disappear!'}
       onPress={() => hideHeader()}>
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
};
export default Test;
```

Is the approach to set `navigationOptions` in the component correct? Because if I do so, it is not applied. Another way I thought about was using `Redux`. So as soon as the button in `Test` is clicked, I would create an action, set the state (for example "`hideHeader`") true and then access the state. But would this be a good solution? And where would I access the state? I would think in `App.ts`, but not sure if it's right.

Can you please help me?

Here is the updated code as suggested by Dmitri:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {Button, Image, View} from 'react-native';

import TestBody from '../../components/organisms/TestBody/TestBody';
import {withNavigation} from 'react-navigation';

interface Props {
  navigation: any;
}

const Test: React.FC<Props> = ({navigation}) => {
  const [showHeader, setShowHeader] = useState(true);
  navigation.setParams({
    header: showHeader ? undefined : null,
  });

  function hideHeader() {
    setShowHeader(!showHeader);
    navigation.setParams({
      header: showHeader ? undefined : null,
    });
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <TestBody />
      <Button
        title={'Press me and the header will disappear!'}
        onPress={() => hideHeader()}></Button>
    </View>
  );
};
export default withNavigation(Test);
```